# Excel lookup and copying the row

Tags: arrays, excel

Hope you are well. I have an issue on excel. I am trying to get the check if a string in a table of sheet 1 is within a column of a table of sheet 2.

Below is a screenshot of the main sheet I am trying to extract data to.

[image: screenshot of main table]

This is the table in sheet 2.

[image]

Now my aim is that if the cell in screenshot 1 matches a cell in the sheet in screenshot 2, the entire row is copied in the R column of screenshot 1. I think the issues I've been having is due to the string I am looking for is only a part of the cells in screenshot 2, not equal.

Does anyone have any advice on how to tackle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what formula you're currently using, but here's what I would suggest to paste in R2 of Sheet 1, and drag down:

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J2, Sheet2!$M$3:$M$12)), Sheet2!$M$3:$M$12)
```

, where J2 is the cell highlighted in screenshot 1, and Sheet2!$M$3:$M$12 refers to your column M of synonyms in screenshot 2.